# selectall uitextfield does not always select all

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, selectall

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField selectAll:self];
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;    
}
```

In the above, the textField selects correctly but when I return from the keyboard and tap the textField for a second time consecutively, it does not select the text.  If I do not pick it consecutively or if I deselect the text before returning from the keyboard, the next focus of that textField selects the text correctly.

How can I select the text in the abovementioned case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a perfect solution(invoke selectAll in next runloop):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField performSelector:@selector(selectAll:) withObject:textField afterDelay:0.f];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this when I can

Comment: You must be a genius! This is a bug on iOS 6 and 7, and I thought the only solution was to file a bug, and wait for a fix. Thanks!

Comment: Filed a bug anyway: #15781101 "UITextField -selectAll: only works every other time".

Comment: This still seems to be a bug as I tried both: `textField.selectAll(nil)` and `textField.perform(#selector(UIResponder.selectAll(_:)), with: textField)` and neither worked more than every other time

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue using Grand Central Dispatch. You can wrap `[textField selectAll:self];` with a `dispatch_async` call and `dispatch_get_main_queue()` as a first parameter.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        // ... code you want to run on the main queue goes here
    }
```

Comment: Simple but important =)